# Calling the class in java, using the name of a class from a string

Tags: java, class

Is there any easy way to achieve this.

Let's say I have an array of string with the name of POJO's in there and I"m trying to print all the list of attributes, is there any way to achieve this easily?\

```
String [] nameofClass;
for(String name:nameofClass)
name.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into BeanUtils ?

Comment: By _name of POJO_ do you mean the name of a variable or the class itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Class.forName(name).getDeclaredFields()` within your `for` loop is probably what you're looking for.

Note that `name` should be the *full path* of the class, i.e. not only `TheClass` but `the.package.to.TheClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. See the example given below:

```
        String [] nameofClass = {"java.lang.Object","java.lang.Thread"};//Give complete path of the class
        try{
            for(String name : nameofClass)
            {
                Class cl = Class.forName(name);
                System.out.println(cl);
                System.out.println("\t"+java.util.Arrays.toString(cl.getDeclaredFields()));
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
```